# How to prevent the page scrolling in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Once the browser is launched, the page is scrolling down in Mozilla firefox causing none of the dropdown lists to work

Comment: How are you launching the browser? What commands are you executing before the scrolling starts? Selenium generally scrolls when you're trying to click on, Actions.moveTo, or edit a field.

Comment: We can't help you without some code and a link to the page or some relevant HTML.